# Wire cladding selection

Tags: wiring

120V wire an be clad in Aluminum 'whips' or in PVC as shown in the photo.
[image]

When is it appropriate (required?) to use Aluminum?  PVC?

Answer (score 1):

The straight metal flex will give the internal conductors a degree of physical protection and will keep the conductors concealed from human contact.  The PVC covered flex, with the right fittings and boxes will add a layer of protection against moisture.